# Replace part of BlockExpression

Tags: c#, .net, expression, expression-trees

Here is a BlockExpression

```
        var compareTo = GetCompareToExpression<TProperty>(expression, parameters);
        var compareToVariable = compareTo.Key;
        var compareToCall = compareTo.Value;
        var zero = Expression.Constant(0, typeof (int));
        LabelTarget ret = Expression.Label(typeof (int));
        var block = Expression.Block(new[] {compareToVariable},
                                     Expression.Assign(compareToVariable, compareToCall),
                                     Expression.IfThen(Expression.NotEqual(compareToVariable, zero),
                                                       Expression.Return(ret, compareToVariable)),
                                     Expression.Label(ret, zero));
        return block;
```

and its debug view:

```
.Block(System.Int32 $compareItem1) {
    $compareItem1 = .Call ($x.Item1).CompareTo($y.Item1);
    .If ($compareItem1 != 0) {
        .Return #Label1 { $compareItem1 }
    } .Else {
        .Default(System.Void)
    };
    .Label
        0
    .LabelTarget #Label1:
}
```

Now I need to replace `.Default(System.Void)` with some custom logic in another method. What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expression`s are immutable, like `string`s. To modify them, you create a copy of them with the changes you need. Normally you use a subclass of [ExpressionVisitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) to do it, like:

```
public class DefaultVoidExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Expression To;

    protected override Expression VisitDefault(DefaultExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Type == typeof(void))
        {
            return this.Visit(To);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.VisitDefault(node);
        }
    }
}
```

and you use it like:

```
var newExpression = new DefaultVoidExpressionReplacer 
    { To = replaceExpression }.Visit(yourExpression);
```

You could even decide to work on a "higher" level: the `Expression.IfThen` level:

```
protected override Expression VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression node)
{
    DefaultExpression de = node.IfFalse as DefaultExpression;

    if (de != null && de.Type == typeof(void))
    {
        return base.Visit(Expression.IfThenElse(node.Test, node.IfTrue, To));
    }

    return base.VisitConditional(node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `BlockExpression` does not allow you to mutate it in place (its `Expressions` property is of type `ReadOnlyCollection<Expression>`, preventing possible modifications) you need to build a new block from the old one.

Expression visitor provides a simple way of coding this up:

```
class DefaultReplacer : ExpressionVisitor {
    protected override Expression VisitGoto(GotoExpression g) {
        if (g.Kind != GotoExpressionKind.Return || g.Value == null) {
            return base.VisitGoto(g);
        }
        // If we are here, it's a return expression with Value.
        // Check if Value represents default(System.Void),
        // and return a replacement expression here
        return ...
    }
}
```

Use this visitor as follows:

```
Expression modifiedBlock = block.Visit(new DefaultReplacer());
```